# Moxtra chat SDK Timeline (Full View)

Tags: javascript, chat

I am trying to implement Moxtra chat SDK Timeline (Full View) for that I registered app and got the access token. then I created new binder and invited new member using emailId now when my friend trying to acces my app he is not able to see new binder and can not access chat window. do I need to replace access token in SDK once new user login to my app or acces_tone is same in code. I am using unique_id authentication method

Answer (score 0):

For the new member you invited using email id, did you use the emailid as the unique id of that new user. If so when the new user you invited is trying to access the timeline via your app, you need to use that emailid as the uniqueid and generate an access token to show the timeline view. If you haven't used the method of uniqueid to invite the new user they will be able to view the binder by logging in via Moxtra app.

Comment: Thanks Ram for reply... Yes my new user is using my app and I am using his emailid as uniqueid and get access token but still this new user is not able to see this binder for which he is invited by me via my app. I have invited using Invite member link I haven't called any REST api while inviting user. Do I need to call REST API?